# Is there a way to enforce the type of an object returned by a function that could return anything?

Tags: php, ide

I am initializing a class where the constructor requires a WP_Post object. The object I would like to pass comes from `get_queried_object()` which could return almost anything. I am using `is_a()` to make sure I have the right type, which "works", but my IDE does not recognize that I have constrained the type.

Is there a way to make it clear to the IDE that I have done my due diligence? I don't want to get in the habit of ignoring my IDE. It has been so nice to me in the past and saved me from so many mistakes. :)

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();

if ( is_singular() && is_a( $queried_object, 'WP_Post' ) ) {
    // Initialize class that requires WP_Post object.
    $class = new ClassThatOnlyAcceptsPostObject( $queried_object );

    // ...
}
```

Comment: If `is_singular()` is true, then the queried object _must_ be a post object.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie that is a good point, however my IDE is not so easily convinced. It doesn't even trust is_a(). Thankfully it does trust instanceof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [what Tom already said](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/359548/108180), using [`instanceof`](https://www.php.net/instanceof) has worked quite well for me. (Actually never heard of `is_a()` before.)

```
if (is_singular() && $queried_object instanceof \WP_Post) {
    // do something
}
```

Both [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan) and my IDE know that after this check, `$queried_object` is an instance of the `WP_Post` class.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out a simple `instanceof` was exactly what I needed.

Sidenote: `is_a()` does a similar thing and matches parent class too, but at considerable cost.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't change what a function returns without modifying it.

You can, however, do several other things:

- Provide type hints on your constructor's arguments, your IDE and PHP will then know that a `\WP_Post` object is required and that nothing else will do
- Use `instanceof` instead of `is_a`, which will be picked up by the IDE
- Perform checks on the return values of the functions and handle their failures
- Convert non-post object return values into something the class will accept
- Refactor things so that you never end up in the situation where  a `WP_Term` or some other kind of object is returned
- Wrap the function in another function that returns either a post or an error value if it's not a post/valid

More importantly, I have to question the value of an object named `PostContent`, and whether it's using classes for the sake of using classes. I don't see what the object can do to a posts content that can't be achieved using standard templates and filters on `the_content`. By rolling your own, you give up a lot of the advantages, filters, and plugin compatibility you get by just using standard APIs and a standard post loop. If this classes job is to process markdown or insert ads, then it needs a more specific name, and can just be created as and when it's needed

Comment: Thanks for the note on the class name :). I just threw in the first thing that popped into my head as a demo. The classes I am actually using are far more useful than this one.

Comment: I edited my class name to avoid confusion. Thanks!